# Computing $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to compute:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}$$

I wanted to use Fubini's theorem for double series but $$ \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}_{(i,j)\in\mathbb{N*^2}}$$ is not a summable family for $$ \forall i>0$$

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i+j}=\infty$$

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to substitute $u=i+j$, so that the sum may be rewritten as $2\sum_{u=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^u}{u}$ which converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: @nullUser Except that there are $u-1$ couples $(i,j)$ such that $i+j=u$...

Comment: Oh, oops. You are correct, my approach is invalid.

Comment: Could it be rewritten as $2 \displaystyle\sum_{u=2}^\infty{(u-1)\frac{(-1)^u}{u}}$?

Comment: @Matt In general, you can't re-arrange or re-combine the terms of a series that is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: (We can, however, rearrange or alter a *finite* number of terms in a conditionally convergent series and obtain the expected answer.)

Comment: @anon: +1, you beat me to it, while I was getting the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about:
$$
-\int_0^1 (-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx = \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
$$
then for each $x \in (0,1)$ we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty -(-x)^{i+j-1} = \frac{x}{(x+1)^2}
$$
and integrate
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}\,dx = \log 2 - \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.193147
$$

**added**

Explanation for summation inside integral ... Two uses of this nice "monotone alternating" convergence theorem:  Suppose $f_1(x) \ge 0\;$ is integrable on $E$ and $f_n(x) \searrow 0$ for almost every  $x \in E$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \int_E f_n(x)\,dx = \int_E \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n f_n(x)\right)\,dx
$$
PROOF: Group the terms in pairs.

**added**

More details now ...
$$
\int_0^1 -(-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx = \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
$$
For fixed $i$, the integrand decreases pointwise a.e. to zero in absolute value, and alternates sign.  Therefore
$$
\int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty-(-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx =
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\int_0^1 -(-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx =
 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
$$
Now this integrand is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty-(-x)^{i+j-1} = \frac{-(-x)^i}{x+1}
$$
As $i$ varies, this decreases a.e. to zero in absolute value, and alternates sign, so
$$
\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty-(-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx=
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty-(-x)^{i+j-1}\,dx=
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}
$$

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: Which is in need of an explanation why the sum signs and the integral can be exchanged.

Comment: The term by term integration theorem or the dominated convergence theorem can be used when there is only one parameter $n\in \mathbb{N}$. What about double integrals?

Comment: @GEdgar: Your answer would be enhanced if you wrote down the functions $f_n$ used in each of the two applications of the MACT.

Comment: @GEdgar Please see my post. The sequence $S_n = \sum\limits_{i \geqslant 1, j \geqslant 1} \left( \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j} \mathbf{1}_{i+j \leqslant n+1} \right)$ has two sub-sequences converging to different values. I would appreciate your feedback/comment.

Comment: @Sasha: the original problem shows what I took to be an iterated sum... not a double sum...  That is, it should be interpreted as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\;\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j}$$  But of course it is not absolutely convergent, so summing in some other order may yield a different answer.  You have shown some of those.  So we conclude the "double sum" does not converge, although the "iterated sum" does.

Comment: A similar problem (and a similar solution) appears in the computation of so-called "Madelung constants"...

Answer (score 7):

Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{i \geqslant 1, j \geqslant 1} \left( \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j} \mathbf{1}_{i+j \leqslant n+1} \right)$. Then
$$
   S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n+1-i} \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j} = 
     \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n+1-i}  \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} \delta_{i+j,m}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i+j} =
     \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n+1-i} \delta_{i+j,m}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m}  =
     \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} (-1)^m\frac{m-1}{m} = \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} (-1)^m - \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^m}{m} = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - (-1)^n \right) + \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1} 
$$

Notice that
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \ln(2) - 1 + H_{n+1/2} - H_n \right) = \ln(2) - 1
$$
and
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{2n+1} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{2n+1}  \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \ln(2) - 1 +H_{n+1/2} - H_{n+1} \right) = \ln(2)
$$
Thus the sequence $S_n$ does not converges as $n$ increases, meaning that the original sum is not defined. The sequence $S_n$ has Cesaro mean, though:
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n S_m = \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln(2) + (\ln(2)-1)\right) = \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: That's a brilliant reasoning ugh !!! A bit weird but brilliant haha :)