# Find the formula of the following expression:

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum_{n_1 , n_2 , \cdots , n_m \ge 1} 
\frac{(-1)^{n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_m}}{n_1 +n_2 +\cdots +n_m}.$$ What about if we change the denominator into $ {n_1}^k + {n_2}^k + \cdots + {n_m}^k $ for $k \ge 2$?

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort*

Comment: Note that if all those sums really start at zero then one term in the sum is $1/0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: so the result is $\infty$ :-)

Comment: No, @Fabian, $1/0$ is undefined, not $\infty.$

Comment: @hkju See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130613/computing-sum-limits-i-1-infty-sum-limits-j-1-infty-frac-1ij/131167#131167) which treats $m=2$ case. I hope you can extend to general $m$.

Comment: It is already treated for $m=2$!!!!!!

Comment: How many users named "hkju" could there be?

Comment: I'm the one, but home pc and ipad gave different user names.

Comment: This is not homework, of course not. Just because of my curiosity.

Comment: I don't know about. How can I do it? I wish ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from here

http://www.ssma.org/Websites/ssma/images/Problems%20Section/Final%20copy%20for%20Jerry%20Oct%2008.pdf

Answer (score 3):

First, of all, the multiple sum
$$
   \sum_{n_1 >0, n_2 >0, \ldots, n_m >0 } \frac{(-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}
$$
does not converge. Indeed, consider regularized version
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  S_k &=& \sum_{n_1 >0, n_2 >0, \ldots, n_m >0 } \frac{(-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m} I_{n_1+n_2+ \cdots + n_m \leqslant k}  \\  &=& \sum_{p=m}^{k} \sum_{n_1 >0, n_2 >0, \ldots, n_m >0 } \frac{(-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m} \delta_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m,p} I_{n_1+n_2+ \cdots + n_m \leqslant k}  \\
 &=& \sum_{p=m}^k \frac{(-1)^p}{p} \sum_{n_1=1}^{p-m+1} \sum_{n_2=1}^{p-m+1} \cdots \sum_{n_m=1}^{p-m+1} \delta_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m,p} \\ &=& 
  \sum_{p=m}^k \frac{(-1)^p}{p} \sum_{n_1=0}^{p-m} \sum_{n_2=0}^{p-m} \cdots \sum_{n_m=0}^{p-m} \delta_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m,p-m} \\
  &=& \sum_{p=0}^{k-m} \frac{(-1)^{p+m}}{p+m} \sum_{n_1=0}^{p} \sum_{n_2=0}^{p} \cdots \sum_{n_m=0}^{p} \delta_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m,p} \\
  &=& \sum_{p=0}^{k-m} \frac{(-1)^{p+m}}{p+m} [z]^p \left( \frac{1-z^{p+1}}{1-z}\right)^m = \sum_{p=0}^{k-m} \frac{(-1)^{p+m}}{p+m} [z]^p \left( \frac{1}{1-z}\right)^m \\
  &=& \sum_{p=0}^{k-m} \frac{(-1)^{p+m}}{p+m} \binom{m+p-1}{p}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The sequence $S_k$ does not converge to any limit. In fact, for large $k$,
$$
   S_k = \frac{(-1)^m}{m} {}_2 F_1 \left(m,m;m+1,-1\right) + \frac{(-1)^k k^{m-2}}{2 (m-1)!} \left( 1+ \mathcal{o}(1)\right)
$$

However, the sum can be regularized, see @G.Edgard's excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130613/computing-sum-limits-i-1-infty-sum-limits-j-1-infty-frac-1ij/131167#131167) discussing $m=2$ case.

The regularization amounts to exchanging the summation and integration here
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
 S_\text{reg} &=& \sum_{n_1=1}^\infty \sum_{n_2=1}^\infty \cdots \sum_{n_m=1}^\infty (-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m} \int_0^1 x^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m-1} \mathrm{d} x \\ &\stackrel{\color\maroon{\text{regularization}}}{=} & \int_0^1 \sum_{n_1=1}^\infty \sum_{n_2=1}^\infty \cdots \sum_{n_m=1}^\infty (-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}  x^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m-1} \mathrm{d} x \\
   &=& \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \right)^m \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x} \\
   &=& \int_0^1 \left( \frac{-x}{1+x} \right)^m \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x} = (-1)^m \int_0^1 x^{m-1} \left(1+x\right)^{-m} \mathrm{d} x \\
  &\stackrel{\color\maroon{\text{by parts}}}{=}& (-1)^m \left. \left( -\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \frac{x^{m-1-k} (1+x)^{1-m+k}}{m-k-1} + \log(1+x) \right) \right|_{0}^1 \\
   &=& (-1)^m \left( \log(2) - \sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \frac{2^{1+k-m}}{m-k-1} \right) \\&\stackrel{k \to m-1-k}{=} &
      (-1)^m \left( \log(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{2^{-k}}{k} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This sum (starting at 1 as noted by Gerry Myerson) can be transformed into an integral by noting that $$
\frac1N=\int_0^\infty\!d\lambda\,e^{-\lambda N}.$$

With $N=\sum_{m=1}^m n_m$, we have (assuming everything is well-defined such that we can interchange summation and integration)
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n_1 =1}^\infty  \sum_{n_2 =1}^\infty \cdots  \sum_{n_m =1}^\infty 
\frac{(-1)^{n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_m}}{n_1 +n_2 +\cdots +n_m}
&= \int_0^\infty\!d\lambda \prod_{i=1}^m \overbrace{\sum_{n_i=1}^\infty (-1)^{n_i} e^{-\lambda n_i}}^{-1/(1+e^{\lambda})}\\
&=(-1)^m\int_0^\infty \!d\lambda\,(1+e^{\lambda})^{-m}\end{align}.$$

The integral remains to be evaluated.  <s>note that
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \!d\lambda\,(1+e^{\lambda})^{-m} &=
\int_0^\infty \!d\lambda\, e^{-m\lambda} \overbrace{(1+e^{-\lambda})^{-m}}^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k-1}{m-1} (-1)^k e^{-km}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k-1}{m-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{m+k},  \end{align} $$
which as far as I see cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.</s>

Comment: Moreover, such sums are divergent for $m \geqslant 2$.

Comment: @Sasha: oh, you are right...

Comment: See my post for the closed form result for your integral, stated at the end of the post.

Answer (score -1):

Define $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nx^n$. The given expression is then $\int_0^1f(x)^mdx$.

Comment: -1, the said integral does not reproduce the sum, rather $\int_0^1 f(x)^m \frac{dx}{x}$ does.